# Image zoomed into CircleAvatar widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to display these avatars in a dropdown in a CircleAvatar widget. However, the image is not fitting properly in the CircleAvatar as shown in the image below. I tried cropping them and changing the size but it's still zoomed into the image. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code for the list of avatars that I'm using to display in the dropdown.

```
   List<AvatarItem> avatars = <AvatarItem>[
    const AvatarItem(avatarString: 'female_avatar_1.png', avatar: Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
        child: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/female_avatar_1.png'), backgroundColor: Colors.white, radius: 30.0,),
      ),
    )),
    const AvatarItem(avatarString: 'male_avatar_1.png', avatar: Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
        child: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/male_avatar_1.png'), backgroundColor: Colors.white, radius: 30.0,),
      ),
    )),
    const AvatarItem(avatarString: 'female_avatar_2.png', avatar: Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
        child: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/female_avatar_2.png'), backgroundColor: Colors.white, radius: 30.0,),
      ),
    )),
    const AvatarItem(avatarString: 'male_avatar_2.png', avatar: Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
        child: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/male_avatar_2.png'), backgroundColor: Colors.white, radius: 30.0,),
      ),
    )),
    const AvatarItem(avatarString: 'gn_avatar.png', avatar: Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
        child: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/gn_avatar.png'), backgroundColor: Colors.white, radius: 30.0,),
      ),
    )),
  ];
```

[image: how it looks now]

Comment: Why are you wrapping CircleAvatar in AvatarItem? Can't you just use CircleAvatar?

Comment: Yiou can also try adding a `fit: BoxFit.cover` to your AssetImage. `cover` or `fitHeight` usually does it for me.

Comment: @LonelyWolf That's just a built in class with avatarString and avatar properties. I'm just using the avatarString to associate it with the correct avatar for the backend

Comment: @Nolence AssetImage does not have a fit property

Comment: @Nolence I just used the child property instead of backgroundImage so I can use Image.asset which has the fit property and that worked

Comment: @SalwaBadreddine Sorry I didn't respond sooner. Glad you got it working!

Comment: @Nolence mean that put CircleAvatar in FittedBox then call fit: BoxFit.cover or BoxFit.fitHeight

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and just came across the answer based on the comments. Here is my similar example code using a FittedBox (also with a border with BoxDecoration) for anyone else who needs :)

```
return Container(
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    child: CircleAvatar(
      radius: 60,
      backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/$image'),
    ),
  ),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.pinkAccent.withOpacity(0.80),
      width: 6,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, by wrapping **CircleAvatar** with **Column**, the issue fixed.

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    CircleAvatar(
      radius: 50,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
          'https://alphatar.vercel.app/api/og?s=A&hex=ffdd00&size=100'),
    )
  ],
),
```